# Find $x\in R$ such that undermentioned numbers create geometric sequence: $\cos(x), \sin(x), \tan(x)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Find $x \in R$ such that undermentioned numbers create geometric sequence:
$\cos(x), \sin(x), \tan(x)$.

I know that $D:x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, k \in Z$.

I could get the result solving this equation:
$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\tan(x)}{\sin(x)}$ but I'm not sure if I can do this because I don't know if $\sin(x) = 0$ or not. Or maybe I should do this for two cases?

EDIT:

Is this method correct?

As we can see in @Rory Daulton post we have: $\sin{x} = r\cos{x}, \tan{x} = r\sin{x}$. We can transform the first equation to the form: $r = \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} = \tan{x}$ (because due to the domain, $\cos{x} \neq 0$). So now we can transform the second equation to the form: $\tan{x} = \tan{x}\sin{x} \iff \tan{x}(\sin{x} - 1) = 0 \iff \tan{x} = 0 \vee \sin{x} = 1$.

Comment: Just solve the equation you have, and if the answer is $x$ and $\sin(x)=0$ or $\cos(x)=0$, check to make sure the solutions are not extraneous.

Comment: $k\in C$ ? Are you sure ? And what do you denote $D$ ?

Comment: Are you sure  that you are asked to rank these functions in that order?

Comment: The domain is actually $D: x\ne k\pi+\frac{\pi}2,\ k\in\Bbb Z$, due to the tangent function. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Rory Daulton You're right. I've written $k \in C$ because in this way we denote this in my native language, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** Yes, you can use cases, but you should use *three* cases. The first case is $\sin x=0$, the second is $\cos x=0$ (since that is also a denominator in your equation), and the third is your equation $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\tan(x)}{\sin(x)}$. Solve those equations and check for extraneous solutions.

**LONGER ANSWER:** It is possible to avoid divisions in our solution method. In a geometric sequence of three elements we have $a_2=ra_1,\ a_3=ra_2$. So from your requirements we get

$$\sin x=r\cos x, \quad \tan x=r\sin x$$

Reversing the second equation and multiplying the two equations together we get

$$r\sin^2 x=r\tan x\cos x$$

Using $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, moving everything to the left, and factoring, we get

$$r\sin x (\sin x-1)=0$$

From that we get *three* cases:

1. $r=0$

From the starting equations we get $\sin x=0,\ \tan x=0$. These have the same solutions $x=k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z$. Checking these answers we get the sequence

$$\pm 1,\ 0, 0$$

which is indeed a geometric sequence, with initial value $-1$ or $1$ and common ratio $0$.

2. $\sin x=0$. This gives us the same solutions as case 1.
3. $\sin x-1=0$. This has the solutions $x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2$. When we try check these answers we get the sequence

$$0,\ 1,\ \text{undefined}$$

which is *not* a geometric sequence for multiple reasons. So these answers are extraneous.

So the final answer is

> $x=k\pi,\ k\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I said "two cases" because $\cos(x)$ cannot be equal zero because of a domain.

Comment: Hm, I've just tried to solve this using your approach and I transformed this two equation to the form: $\tan{x}(\sin{x} - 1) = 0$ and then I got the sam result. Is it correct?

Comment: @tdudzik: I can't say the method is correct without seeing it, but you do get the correct final results that way. It is not clear that you can easily avoid checking the case of the common ratio $r$ being zero, though there is a valid way to do so. How did you avoid checking that case?

Comment: I've updated my question and putted my current method there.